# Pdftk will not work through PHP

Tags: php, pdf, pdftk

I am trying to use `pdftk` through PHP.  It works perfectly through the terminal, and some other commands work with PHP.  For example:

```
echo 'PWD: ' . shell_exec('pwd') . '<br>';
echo 'LS: ' . shell_exec('cd processes && ls') . '<br>';
echo 'PDFTK: ' . shell_exec('/usr/bin/pdftk --help');
```

returns the following:

```
PWD: /opt/lampp/htdocs/WebApp  
LS: auto_complete_test.php .... other files I have  
PDFTK:
```

I cannot get any commands involving `pdftk` to work through PHP, and I have run out of ideas.  Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that the user `www-data` has the permission to execute `/usr/bin/pdftk`

Comment: I have changed the permissions but the output is still the same.

Comment: Try `shell_exec('/usr/bin/pdftk --help 2>&1')` to see the `stderr` output, maybe you can get more information from that.

Comment: That gave me an error:
`libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found`

I looked it up and was able to fix the issue by reading this post:
https://community.bitnami.com/t/libstdc-so-6-issue/20589

Thank you.